# Store List elements and their idices in extra table using JPA

Tags: jpa

Let's say I have an object `Car`, which contains a `List<Wheel>`. I have four wheel positions and each position can take one or no wheel. I modeled it with `@ManyToMany` as it is necessary for this specific case.

The `Car`:

```
@Entity
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="CAR_WHEEL", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "WHEEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    private List<Wheel> wheels;

    // constructors, getters, setters ...

}
```

The `Wheel`:

```
@Entity
public class Wheel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="wheels")
    private List<Car> cars;

    // constructors, getters, setters ...

}
```

In my view, I save the wheels to specific positions inside the list. For example, if you have the following relationship:

Position 1: Wheel 3

Position 2: *No wheel*

Position 3: Wheel 1

Position 4: *No wheel*

The List would look like this: `[my.model.Wheel@fbc9ffe, null, my.model.Wheel@3d14ead8, null]`.

I now want to have a table `WHEEL_POSITION`, which would look like this, after saving the `Car`:

```
WHEEL_POSITION
id      wheel       position
1       3           0
2       null        1
3       1           2
4       null        3
```

The position is the index of the `Wheel`-object inside the list.

How do I have to proceed, so that this table is created by JPA?

Comment: You save the positioning in a List using `@OrderColumn` which you haven't used. Clearly that will not save the position in the List at both sides though ...

Comment: Thank you very much Neil, this was exactly the annotation I was missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, to add an `@OrderColumn` annotation to the entity `Car` (thanks to Neil Stockton):

```
@Entity
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="CAR_WHEEL", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "WHEEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Wheel> wheels;

    // constructors, getters, setters ...

}
```

It adds a new column to the table.